# MySQL - query ordered by date failing to get the latest record

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a database set up as follows:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c5fc

What I'm looking to do is get a list of each store, and their last budget amount (Each schedule's total in the budget * their apportionment for that schedule / 100).

Some stores might not have apportionments set for the last budget, so I need the last budget where they have an apportionment set, or NULL if no apportionment has been set or no budget exists.

I've got the following SQL query:

```
SELECT s.StoreID,s.CentreID, budgetcalc.amount, budgetcalc.BudgetDate FROM store as s
LEFT JOIN centre on s.CentreID = centre.CentreID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT BudgetDate, SUM(sch.Amount*appt.Percentage/100) as amount, appt.StoreID from budget b
    INNER JOIN schedule as sch on b.BudgetID = sch.BudgetID
    INNER JOIN apportionment as appt on sch.ScheduleID = appt.ScheduleID 
    GROUP BY appt.StoreID, b.BudgetID
    ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(b.BudgetDate,'%d-%m-%y') DESC
) as budgetcalc on s.StoreID = budgetcalc.StoreID
GROUP BY s.StoreID
ORDER BY s.StoreID, STR_TO_DATE(budgetcalc.BudgetDate,'%d-%m-%y') DESC;
```

However this has the issue of not returning the last year, it will return a previous year seemingly at random regardless of the order in which I return the subquery.

Comment: Why to use `ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(b.BudgetDate,'%d-%m-%y') DESC` your table definition says the data type is `date` so just do as `order by b.BudgetDate desc` and same for the outer order by

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I originally thought the issue was because I was trying to order on a date rather than a datetime or similar, and I forgot to remove it.. But the issue is the same either way.

Comment: You are grouping by the storeID, so MySQL will return one row for each store id. Which budget is returned for that store is not defined, so might be the first, latest or any other one.

Comment: @Kickstart But because I'm grouping by the BudgetID as well, wouldn't it return the amount for every budget for every store, which is then ordered by the date end and filtered by the ON statement?

Comment: Your inner query groups by budgetid, but assuming you can have multiple budget ids for each storeid, which one is matched is not defined (the order by in the sub query is irrelevant)

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to work out from just the table declarations, but you need to get the latest budget date for each store, then join that against your sub query that gets the budget details for each store / budget.

Untested but something like this:-

```
SELECT s.StoreID,
        s.CentreID, 
        budgetcalc.amount, 
        budgetcalc.BudgetDate 
FROM store as s
LEFT OUTER JOIN centre ON s.CentreID = centre.CentreID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT appt.StoreID, 
            MAX(BudgetDate) AS latestBudgetDate
    FROM budget b
    INNER JOIN schedule as sch ON b.BudgetID = sch.BudgetID
    INNER JOIN apportionment as appt ON sch.ScheduleID = appt.ScheduleID 
    GROUP BY appt.StoreID
) latest_budget
ON s.StoreID = latest_budget.StoreID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT BudgetDate, 
            appt.StoreID, 
            SUM(sch.Amount*appt.Percentage/100) as amount 
    FROM budget b
    INNER JOIN schedule as sch ON b.BudgetID = sch.BudgetID
    INNER JOIN apportionment as appt ON sch.ScheduleID = appt.ScheduleID 
    GROUP BY appt.StoreID, b.BudgetID
) as budgetcalc 
ON latest_budget.StoreID = budgetcalc.StoreID
AND latest_budget.latestBudgetDate = budgetcalc.BudgetDate
ORDER BY s.StoreID, 
        budgetcalc.BudgetDate DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This code almost works, however I had duplicate StoreIDs being returned. After looking through how you had completed it, it gave me an idea which seems to work. Thank you for the explanation into why my original idea didn't work, I see where I was going wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

With help from Kickstart, this is the answer that works:

```
SELECT s.StoreID,s.CentreID, SUM(sch.Amount*appt.Percentage/100) as amount, b.BudgetDate FROM store as s
INNER JOIN centre on s.CentreID = centre.CentreID
LEFT JOIN budget as b on b.BudgetID = 
    (
        SELECT budget.BudgetID from budget 
        INNER JOIN schedule on budget.BudgetID = schedule.BudgetID 
        INNER JOIN apportionment on schedule.ScheduleID = apportionment.ScheduleID
        where CentreID = s.CentreID AND apportionment.StoreID = s.StoreID
        ORDER BY BudgetDate DESC limit 1
    )
LEFT JOIN schedule as sch on b.BudgetID = sch.BudgetID
LEFT JOIN apportionment as appt on sch.ScheduleID = appt.ScheduleID AND appt.StoreID = s.StoreID
GROUP BY s.StoreID
ORDER BY s.StoreID ASC;
```